# Store data in a Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

I have created a gRPC client that receives data from a server.
The client runs as a Azure WebJob.

The received data looks like that there is a replay id for each message.
I currently store this replay id locally as a file. The received replay id is appended to the file.
The Replay Id is needed so that if there is a problem it can continue from that ID.

If I run the client locally this is not a problem, but I think that as a WebJob is not ideal.
My problem currently is that the files that are created/modified at runtime are stored here:

`C:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\SalesforceIngestor.App\ev4ygzfw.ezh`

If the WebJob restarts for any reason, the data in the replayIdStorage.txt file will be lost.

Is there any way to safely store data in a WebJob so that it can be retrieved after a restart?

Or would Azure Blob Storage be a better option?

Comment: Asking "Best way to ..." is one of _the_ best ways to get the question closed as opinion-based.

Comment: No need to apologize. It really often is just an unlucky choice of words. In the end you are looking for a suitable solution to efficiently persist some data, am I right?

Comment: So, an "Id". Is that a single Guid? Or do you need more than that persisted? How would you need to access the data in case you actually needed to replay?

Comment: it is like a Guid, after each received message there is a new ID which is stored.
When the app is restarted, the last saved ID is always loaded.

Comment: So, in principle, you need to store _one single Id_, which is the "last seen" one?

Comment: Yes, that's basically exactly how it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried below .Net Web Job code and can able to store the Web Jobs data of the web app in my storage account container.***

**Code:**

***Program.cs:***

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace WebJob1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

            if (config.IsDevelopment)
            {
                config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
            }

            var host = new JobHost(config);
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
    }
}
```

**Function.cs:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace WebJob1
{
    public class Functions
    {
        private const string ConnectionStringName = "AzureWebJobsStorage"; 

        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
            log.WriteLine(message);
            string replayId = GenerateReplayIdFromMessage(message);
            StoreReplayIdInBlobStorage(replayId);
        }

        private static string GenerateReplayIdFromMessage(string message)
        {
            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        private static void StoreReplayIdInBlobStorage(string replayId)
        {
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(ConnectionStringName));
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var containerName = "replayids"; 
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            container.CreateIfNotExists();

            var blobName = "replayIdStorage.txt"; 
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            blob.UploadText(replayId);
        }
    }
}
```

**app.config:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <!-- The format of the connection string is "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY" -->
        <!-- For local execution, the value can be set either in this config file or through environment variables -->
        <add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="<storage_connec_string>" />
        <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="<storage_connec_string>" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

I got two containers created in my storage account at Azure portal as below,

[image]

I got **Id** in **azure-webjobs-hosts** container as below,

[image]

And got below in **azure-jobs-host-output** container,

[image]

[image]

Then, I **published** my code to **web app** as below,

[image]

It successfully **published** to **web jobs** in **web app** at **Azure Portal**. Then, I click on **Run** to start running the web job as below,

[image]

Web Job **running** started successfully as below,

[image]

[image]

Then, I got **web app** details **stored** im my storage account **azure-jobs-host-output** container as below,

[image]